# AngularJS: accessing scope in $resource factory definition

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, pusher

I'm running an AngularJS app that incorporates Pusher for real-time updates of models. I'd like to trigger an action in a scope when pusher sends updated data for an AngularJS resource in the factory definition.

I have a resource defined as follows:

```
TS.app.factory "Object", ($resource) ->
  Object = $resource("objects/:publicToken", {publicToken: "@public_token"}, {update: {method: "PUT"}})

  # Checks for updates to object data via Pusher.
  Object::watch = ->
    channelName = "private-12345"

    # See if we've already subscribed to this channel.
    channel = Namespace.pusher.channel(channelName)

    # If not, subscribe.
    channel ||= Namespace.pusher.subscribe(channelName)

    # Update data if we get new info from pusher.
    channel.bind "updated info", (data) =>
      # THIS GETS RUN WHEN PUSHER SENDS UPDATED DATA.
      for key, value of data
        this[key] = value
      # TRIGGER ACTION HERE
```

I'd like to set variables in this resource's scope here. I know that for methods like $get, the scope will automatically update, but I don't know how to do that in this situation. How can I access the scope here?

If there are other better (or more Angular-y) ways to do this, what are they?

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't want your services knowing about your models or accessing them directly.  It sounds like you'd want to use the observer pattern on the service and have any controllers that care about getting notification subscribe to your service.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/sqCZz/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
    <div ng-repeat="notification in notifications">{{notification}}</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .factory('TestService', function () {
    var _subscribers = [];

    setInterval(function () {
        // every 1 second, notify all subscribers
        console.log(_subscribers);
        angular.forEach(_subscribers, function (cb) {
            cb('something special @ ' + new Date());
        });
    }, 2500);

    return {
        subscribe: function (cb) {
            _subscribers.push(cb);
        }
    };
})
    .controller('testController', function ($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.notifications = ['nothing yet'];

    TestService.subscribe(function (notification) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.notifications.push('got ' + notification);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In your first sentence, did you mean controllers instead of models?

Comment: I think this would be a reasonable solution if I only had one Object, but I've actually got around 100-200 of them. Will test, but I'm guessing this would deteriorate performance.